# Setting up recipients and dates to be sent in Postmaster Module

Tags: tags, postmaster

I am trying to configure a parcel to be sent out once everyday, i have "+1 day" in the field, but it is not sending at all, as for the recipients section i have the tag {member:screen_name} for "from" and {member:email} for the "to" this is just temporary so I can test to see if it works properly.

Any Help would be great!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the details of of the parcel you have setup, and which settings you have put these values into? (You have "+1 day" in _which_ field?)

Comment: I have {parcel:entry_date format="%m%d/%Y"} in the Post Date Specific field, and then i have "+1 day" in the Send Every field

Comment: Can you also elaborate how you have set up which user to send too? i.e. how is `{member:` defined?

Comment: {member:email} says that it will send an email to any member of the group in which the author belongs to, {member:screen_name} will display the screen name of that member sending to, in the same member group as the author

Comment: But what is triggering the parcel - entries in a specific channel? The emails sent by parcels are meant to be triggered by - and specific to - individual entries. So if you don't have new entries, no email will be triggered.

Comment: If I am looking to send an email every 2 weeks, is the notification in postmaster the way to go because it will then just send on a schedule? Will all of my template code and logic that i have in the parcel I made work in notifications?